# Clear local storage when chrome is closed (not when particular tab is closed)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, local-storage

Is there a way to clear the local storage everytime we close the chrome. I have find a lot of answers on stackoverflow which clears localStorage when we close the tab, but is there a way to clear only when chrome closes ?

Comment: There's no way to reliably detect that Chrome is closing from an extension. It was asked many times here. Even if you will check number of windows, your extension just won't have time to do anything once Chrome  starts shutting down.

Comment: Would when Chrome is opened be a viable alternative?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), it maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session (**as long as the browser is open**, including page reloads and restores)

> data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores.

Comment: It's not obvious that this answers the question asked. As I read it, the goal is to clear `localStorage` that's being populated by the website, so no control over that.

Comment: To clarify `sessionStorage`, it is isolated by tabs. It means that if you open the same url twice in two different tabs, the sessionStorage won't be shared.

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome://settings/cookies#cont
```

You can clear the local storage just by typing the site in the search field.